# Three.js problems with mobile device orientation

Tags: javascript, android, three.js

I'm bug testing a web app that was written in three.js and I've had reports of users on tablets (specifically Android) getting some strange behavior from the scene.

[image: Image with error]

Here is the same view as it should be rendered:

[image]

It happens when they change device orientation but has also been reported, on a 2 in 1 tablet running windows, in Microsoft Edge. The user gets a similar error when swiping their finger across the screen (the browser wants to scroll vertically and horizontally but then jumps back to the fixed view).  I haven't seen this happen on a desktop yet.

Here is my onWindowResize function:

```
 function onWindowResize(event) {

    SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    composer.reset();

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I noticed that this same error occurs when resizing the window on some desktop PCs and laptops.  I haven't found a consistent way to recreate the problem, it seems to happen stochastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I was resizing the fxaa composer and setting it to screen width and height:

```
effectFXAA.uniforms['resolution'].value.set(1 / SCREEN_WIDTH, 1 / SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

when I should have been using canvas width and height:

```
effectFXAA.uniforms['resolution'].value.set(1 / canvas.width, 1 / canvas.height);
```

Changing this fixed my issue and I can now resize without any problems.